# Creating documents in SOLR..?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, schema, document

i am new to Apache SOLR..n i am learning how to create documents in SOLR..

---

My scenario : In my RDBMS database, i have the following scenario :

> A "cars" table "**jc_cars**" : *id, name, extra*
>
> An "attributes" table "**jc_attributes**" : *id*, *attributeName*
>
> A **Many-to_many table** between Attribute and Cars :
>   "**jc_car_attributes**" : *carID*, *attributeID* , *value*
>
> An "article" table : **jc_articles** : *id, title, description*
>
> A **Many-to-many table** between Article and Cars :
>   "**jc_car_articles**" : *articleID, carID*

Now what I want is :

- Searching ***All the Cars with their Attributes (like Price)***
- Searching ***All the Articles related to this Car***

Actually I want results when i make the following the query :

- ***Cars with price less than 400000*** : Should give Car Details and
  related Articles
- ***Hyundai Accent*** : Should give Car Details and related Articles
- and So on.....

So how should i create the Corresponding document and Schema.xml..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr has a flat index, so you can't really have a list of relations with multiple values (e.g. a relation with both a name and a value, like your attributes).

For the articles, you can provide the IDs of related articles in a multi-valued field, then do a separate lookup for these either (a) in your database (b) in another solr core.

For the attributes, if you have a fixed list of attributes you can join these to `cars` and read each attribute into its own field. If you do not have a fixed list of attributes, you'll also have to resort to a separate core, doing essentially the reverse of what you would do for articles; do a lookup in the attributes core then lookup the specific cars from your cars core.

Comment: thanx for the answer..but since i am new to Solr..so i dint understand your answer much...When u said another Solr core..did u mean another "request handler"..??

Comment: [Solr cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) are separate indexes for documents which do not have the same structure. In your example: `cars` and `attributes` and `articles`.